# BASIC PYTHON - same result for different variable

Tags: python, variables

I am still a beginner. I would like to know why the results are same and working succesfully for the following 2 different commands? also i want to know the difference between them.

when i give the variable as following the command is working

```
import turtle

black_turtle = turtle.Turtle()

black_turtle.forward(100)
```

also when i type the variable as shown, the command is working

```
import turtle

black_turtle = turtle

black_turtle.forward(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

*turtle.Turtle is a class*

The first black_turtle is called turtle and is referenced by the module name, the black_turtle = turtle.Turtle() method creates a new turtle and most of the time, it's used to set it to a variable.

If anything, you can try these to understand better:

```
import turtle

black_turtle = turtle
red_turtle = turtle

black_turtle.forward(100)
red_turtle.left(90)
black_turtle.right(-90)
red_turtle.forward(100)
```

Here, the turtle will go forward for 100 pixels and then comeback where it started, even tho we used red_turtle instead of black turtle. It overwrites.

So if you'd like 2 different turtles, you would use turtle.Turtle() :

```
import turtle

black_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
red_turtle = turtle.Turtle()

black_turtle.forward(100)
red_turtle.left(90)
black_turtle.right(-90)
red_turtle.forward(100)
```

Now you see 2 different turtles doing what they are asked to do :)